# How will I get one of the value from the data attribute

Tags: jquery, data-url

I have a data attribute which is having multiple values. How will I get one value out of it ?

```
<div data-url='{"header-url" : "src/one.html","footer-url" : "src/two.html","content-url" : "src/three.html"}'></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
 var headerContent = $('div').attr('data-url');
 console.log(headerContent)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/taGBL/19/

Comment: Which value you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **`bracket notation`**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var headerContent = $('div').data('url');

    console.log(headerContent['header-url']);
    console.log(headerContent['footer-url']);
    console.log(headerContent['content-url']);

});
```

[**`Fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/taGBL/20/)

Answer (score 1):

See you can use **`Bracket Notation`** which is available in javascript also you don't need to use `.attr()` method of jQuery here as you have a `data-*` prefix in that attribute so you can surely make use of `.data()` method of `jQuery` which works in your case:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var headerContent = $('div').data('url');
   console.log(headerContent['header-url']); // <--with bracket notation.
});
```

or if you want to get all the values then you can use `$.each()` method for this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var headerContent = $('div').data('url');
   $.each(headerContent, function(k, v){
       console.log(v); // this logs all the three values.
   });
});
```

[Fiddle with `$.each()` method.](http://jsfiddle.net/taGBL/21/)